# How can we update student selections?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a db with two collections. Students collection has a field named "student_bookselections" that keeps the ids of books. Content of this field will often be changed or updated.

1. How can we add or delete ids to student_bookselections?
2. Is this a decent way to relate the collections?

students collection

```
                array(
                "student_id" => 4,
                "student_fullname" => $studentfullname,
                "student_bookselections" => 'id1,  id34, id788 ... ... id4'

                )
```

books collection

```
                array(
                "book_id" => 4354,
                "book_title" => $title,
                "book_author" => $author,

                )
```

Comment: You using Mongodb right ?

Comment: @ S.Visser : yes I am using  mongodb but I am a newby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To update**

```
<?php

  $mongo = new Mongo();
  $db = $mongo->selectDB("Your_Database");

  $student = $db->students;

  $update = array("$set" => array("student_bookselections" => "your ids"));
  $where = array("student_id" => 4);
  $student->update($where,$update);

?>
```

**To insert**

```
<?php

  $mongo = new Mongo();
  $db = $mongo->selectDB("Your_Database");

  $student = $db->students;

  $insert = array("student_fullname" => "Stefan", "student_bookselections" => "your ids" );
  $student->insert($insert);

?>
```

**To Remove**

```
<?php

  $mongo = new Mongo();
  $db = $mongo->selectDB("Your_Database");

  $student = $db->students;

  $student->remove(array("ID" => 4));

?>
```

**Relation**
(See post from Crhis)

```
Users(
    "student_id" => 4,
    "student_fullname" => $studentfullname
 )

Books(
    "book_id" => 4,
    "book_title" => $title,
    "book_author" => $author
 )

Selections(
    "selection_id" => 4,
    "student_id" => $studentid,
    "book_id" => $bookid
 )
```

**Select with this relation**

```
<?php

  $mongo = new Mongo();
  $db = $mongo->selectDB("Your_Database");

  $selection = $db->selections;

  $res = $student->find(array("student_id" => $student_id));

?>
```

Comment: Let's say student_selections contains ids 1,2,3,4,5.  so I want to delete 2 and  add 9 to the list.  Does your code do it this way?

Comment: @Mustafa, for that you really need to change you database structure. Because else you make it yourself really hard.

Comment: So you suggest a new collection for selections - I tought to keep them in students collection. Because it would be easy to reach selections inside students collection than searching relatively huge seperate collection for selections.  Am I on the wrong way?

Comment: Please use `new MongoClient()`

Comment: @WahyuKristianto you are right, the `Mongo()` class is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off having a third table to link students to books, your current implementation is not normalized.

```
Users(
    "student_id" => 4,
    "student_fullname" => $studentfullname
 )

Books(
    "book_id" => 4,
    "book_title" => $title,
    "book_author" => $author
 )

Selections(
    "selection_id" => 4,
    "student_id" => $studentid,
    "book_id" => $bookid
 )
```

You can then define relationships with foreign keys to link the tables, and more importantly each row is relating to one piece of information. If you wanted to know all book selections for a certain student

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Selections WHERE student_id = $student_id");
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ah apologies didn't see mongol, ignore my insert. Combine my suggestion of a new table with the helpful code in the other answer and I think you'll have a good solution.